# Moving cursor within TMUX on MAC

Tags: tmux, macos

When I launch `tmux` from the terminal, and attempt to move the cursor between words on one terminal line, the shortcuts that work in a default terminal don't appear to apply. e.g. <kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> does move the cursor one word back(**albeit with a terminal bell**) but <kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> doesn't move it one word forward. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> doesn't move the cursor to the beginning of the line, neither does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> to the end of the line and so on. I tried the equivalent of <kbd>Home</kbd> i.e. <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> but that capitalizes the next letter and the equivalent for <kbd>End</kbd> which is <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> capitalizes the entire word and moves to the next word. I don't even get the recursive search on trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>.

```
%cat ~/.tmux.conf
setw -g mouse on
setw -g mode-keys vi
set-option -g prefix C-b

tmux -V
tmux 3.1b
```

Terminal Version:Version 2.10 (433) on MacOS Catalina

Comment: So what happens when you put your shell _back into_ `emacs` mode?  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP It works . But why does everything fall apart (including the recursive search) if vi mode is enabled?

Comment: That question takes a falsehood as its premise.  Nothing has fallen apart in the first place.

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks, got it. I'd set the VI mode in the ZSH shell which was causing this issue (which was using the VIM bindings). Referring to the VIM mode key bindings of ZSH resolved it.